# I need my C# settings file to be static (as in one place)

Tags: c#, configuration, settings

Currently I have the the default `Settings.settings` file that I access through `Properties.Settings.Default`.

But this config is saved in my user's `appdata` folder. How can I get there to be only one config file kept in the same dir as the exe that is universal AND can be changed at runtime?

Comment: Are you looking to do this because of a portable application, or are you just trying to prevent each individual user from having their own settings for an executable?

Comment: Well, the issue I have is this. My app is a combination console and forms app - the app runs in a console (the gui is for setting parameters) , and is called/run by another app. Since it is called by the wrapper app, it doesn't know to use my user settings and ends up using defaults. So I guess the next ? is can I tell the app where to find my user config in code?

Comment: UPDATE: it appears that the path used to the user settings is dynamic based on if the assembly is strong-named or not. I need to investigate further.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't count on the user having permission to modify files in the same directory as the exe, particularly if that directory is under Program Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the Properties.Settings feature, as the [documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx) says:

> Application-scope settings are read only, and can only be changed at
>   design time or by altering the .exe.config file in
>   between application sessions. User-scope settings, however, can be
>   written at run time, just as you would change any property value. The
>   new value persists for the duration of the application session. You
>   can persist changes to user settings between application sessions by
>   calling the Settings.Save method. These settings are saved in the
>   User.config file.

An alternate approach would be to use the System.IO API to read and write a configuration file you design yourself.

Comment: I, for one, always use a `Dictionary<string,object>` for my settings. It is serializable and works very well!

Comment: @Vercas Dictionaries aren't serializable...at least not with the XmlSerializer.  I have recently been using a custom serializable dictionary class for settings.

Comment: @NickAldwin If you don't want ordinary users to mess with the settings file, use the BinaryFormatter...

Comment: @Vercas We've been burned by that before (version incompatibilities cause files to become unreadable) and we've found it helpful in many support cases to be able to quickly edit the files by hand (both for users AND for us).

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna have problems with UAC on Vista/7.
Please, do keep vital application data files such as the "Settings" in a hidden and accessible directory - AppData.
UAC allows access to this directory and it's subdirectories.

If you want to share the file among all the users, you might want to use the "CommonAppData" directory, but you need administrator rights to write there.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the settings in the application configuration file in the `<applicationSettings>` tag.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229207.aspx for documentation on the  tag.

Eg (xxxxx -> the Visual Studio project name, yyyyy-> actual setting in the Settings file).

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <xxxxxx.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="yyyyyy"
        serializeAs="String">
        <value>some_value</value>
      </setting>
    </ReprintProcess.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve it without extending and heavily modifying Properties.Settings class.
Therefore I would recommend either writing your own Settings Management wrapper or alternative libraries such as [Settings4Net](http://settings4net.codeplex.com)